# object HTMLCollection error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to disable HTML elements by iterating through the elements in JavaScript which I am getting from the list generated by `getElementsByTagName(ínput')`

for few iterations it works fine, but when there are more iterations I am getting an object HTMLCollection problem and it becomes an infinite loop.

the JavaScript code is:

```
else if(selectedValue == 'No' || selectedValue == 'no' || selectedValue == 'NO')
    {
     var elelst =document.getElementsByClassName(questionId+'_'+'true');
     alert(elelst.length);
     for(var i=0; i<elelst.length;i++)
     {
         if(elelst[i].type != undefined)
          {
          elelst[i].value= '';
          elelst[i].disabled= true;
          }
         else
         {
           var inputs = elelst[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
           alert(inputs);
          for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; ++i)
          {
           inputs[i].disabled=true; 
           }   
          }

     }
```

Comment: If you reuse the variable `i` you are perhaps getting in trouble. Rename the second one to `j` and then you should be fine. Do a `console.log(i)` within the loop to check.

Comment: Thx Thomas Junk I have used different variables now it is working...

Comment: it is worth noting that, in future, you should copy and paste the exact error code generated in the console to help people to fix any problems. if the program does not throw an actual error, then define the problem as unexpected/unwnated behaviour or something similar instead